# Overheating in ubuntu 16.04 in Lenovo G50-80

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, overheating

I have lenovo G50-80 laptop.But it starts heating up ( Specially top right of touch pad but not the touch pad itself  ) when I using Ubuntu.I had this problem in ubuntu 14.04 too.
I test many answers of same questions in this site but they don't work at all.
(I run windows 8.1 in this laptop without any problem. )

Answer (score 1):

Is the fan working?

Try installing tlp:
`sudo apt update && sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw`

If you have some problem, [here](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) is the site.

Comment: Thank you but they don't work :(