# Problem with fan(cooler) in Lenovo G 40-80 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, lenovo, overheating, fan

I have a Lenovo G40-80 notebook with i5-5200U 2.2GHz and Intel HD Graphics 5500 and the fan run very slow. 
How can I improve the fan velocity?

I tried this, but I don't had success: [Overheating in ubuntu 16.04 in Lenovo G50-80](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768938/overheating-in-ubuntu-16-04-in-lenovo-g50-80)

These too, no success: [Fan not running in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703580/fan-not-running-in-ubuntu-14-04)

I don't have problems when I used windows 8.

What's the best solution for this on Ubuntu?

Comment: How does it work in a 16.04 live session?

Comment: The fan running slow can be a good thing unless your laptop is burning your wrists. Open terminal with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` and type `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp` and update your question with the results.

Comment: I agree with @WinEunuuchs2Unix, if your computer overheating, but the fans still run slow, then there's a problem

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I run the commnad, and the result was: 4100

Comment: OP is on 14.04, not 16.04

Comment: @MikaelAraujo please see my answer below and post new comments below it.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The result for this command is **54000**. But my temperature are between 54 - 75 Celsius. The fan is running very slow yet.

Comment: @MikaelAraujo My system runs about the same temperature under Ubuntu 16.04. I'll see if I can reboot with Ubuntu 14.04 later to see if it runs 10-20 degrees cooler there like I think it did.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp`, this command is really magic, the fan auto-control program of my laptop didn't work, but I found this command can trigger the detection of the problem. So, with running this command regularly, the fan auto-control program starts to work. Cannot figure out why, maybe the program doesn't flush the result to these files, and `cat` will force the program to flush the result.

Answer (score 1):

Install cpufrequtils:

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

Go to terminal and type:

```
cpufreq-info
```

If your laptop is running intel_pstate, we have to disable that.

In terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And edit this line so it looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_pstate=disable quiet splash"
```

Then, reboot, and type this in terminal:

```
sudo cpufreq-set -g ondemand
```

What this command does is set a governor that controls the CPU based on load. Therefore, if you aren't running many intensive programs, your CPU will idle at a lower clock speed, thereby using less power and using less heat.

Now, if this doesn't work, we can try to manually control your fans. It is unlikely you will be able to control them, as you have a consumer laptop that is relatively recent- there probably aren't drivers for the fans.

```
sudo apt-get lm-sensors
```

See if your fan is there, with its RPM reading. If it is, then we can control the fan.

See this thread for more information: [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

Comment: I tried the solution above, but I doesn't have sucess. Probably my hardware can't detected in this version. I'm trying tests in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Wait, you're on 14.04? Upgrade. Broadwell is a new CPU architecture, and 16.04 supports it far better than 14.04.

Comment: I think It is a bad idea to disable intel_pstate because it works in conjunction with termald to keep the laptop's fan running at the appropriate speed. Also "ondemand" is being deprecated in newer versions in favor of "powersave" and "performance" as the only two options I believe.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Well, on my Skylake machine I had to disable intel_pstate to achieve sleep states farther than C3. After doing that my laptop ran about 10-15 C cooler and the fan is far quieter now. OP has a Broadwell CPU, which is one generation lower and also might have issues due to its newer 14nm process. Haswell is currently the newest Intel CPU that has complete support in linux.

Comment: @patrickyi but he is on Ubuntu 14.04. Your steps when on 16.04 make sense and I should try them too. When I was on Ubuntu 14.04 level I didn't have hotter than normal CPU. It was after upgrade to 16.04 kernel level that turbo boost was turned on and temps got hot. I notice using intel `powertop` that my C7 is running 70% in idle mode. It's a problem effecting everything past my 3rd generation Ivy Lake I think. With Bay Trail I see there is a `intel_cstate.idle_max=1` bug fix that has to be put into the kernel too. **sigh**.

Comment: @patrickyi I did a downgrad for tests. I did the same results. And the results of the command `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp` is *54000* in average, but the range is 54 to 75 Celsius.

Comment: @MikaelAraujo 54 C isn't a bad result either. That is pretty much perfectly normal.

Comment: @PatrickNegus Yes. Same results like me. 54 to 54ºC it's not bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your fan is running slow and you are concerned but, you do not have a problem here.

Your temperature was revealed by typing:

```
cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
```

And the result returned was 41 degrees Celsius. **This is a very good result!**

By comparison my machine the fan runs on medium and the temperature is 65 degrees Celsius. All though the keyboard is "warm" it is not "hot" so I consider mine to be "good".

Your fan is automatically controlled by the ACPI. In order to make your fan run faster, you'd have to make the CPU hotter and the best way to do that is run some 3D games with high frame rates.

The recommendation to upgrade to 16.04 may make your machine run hotter (and therefore the fan run faster) as it for me with my--Intel 3rd generation Ivy Bridge i7 3630QM CPU.

Comment: You have a 3rd generation Ivy Bridge CPU, which has very good support in previous Ubuntu versions such as 14.04. However, OP has a Broadwell-U CPU, which is far newer and has fairly scanty support among older kernels. Upgrading to 16.04 would probably help. Although, 41 C is very low to begin with.

Comment: My 3d gen ran about 50 C under older kernels so his 5th gen at 41 C seems about right. After upgrade to Kernel 4.4 under Ubuntu 16.04 my temps rose to 80 to 90 C and I got concerned. Hopped to Kernel 4.6.3, then 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.7.3 and now sitting on 4.7.5. Coupled with other tweaks my temp right now is 65 C. I outlined much of my "tweaks" in [http://askubuntu.com/questions/827939/ubuntu-15-10-various-types-of-freezes-and-now-unexpected-shutdown] I should update the pstate section there to point to your answer here.

Comment: Yes @WinEunuuchs2Unix the temperature is 41ºC in average. It's good, no. I think that this thread is solved.

Comment: 41ºC is a great temperature and I only wish mine was that good (currently 67). Please mark one of the answers as a solution (by clicking the check mark) to clear it off the "unanswered" list.